# Exception when use SaveChanges() in Entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

i wrote code which using EF model based now i want to add som entries to my tables as below:

```
 protected void cmdOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {

                Validate();
                if (Page.IsValid)
                    using (var db = new KishModelContainer())
                    {
                        EditId = Request["Id"].ChangeType<int>(0);
                        if (EditId == 0)
                        {
                            var obj = new Entities.Db.Salon();
                            obj.Name = txtName.Text;
                            obj.Address = txtAddress.Text;
                            obj.Capacity = Convert.ToInt32(txtCapacity.Text);
                            obj.ServiceProviderId = txtProviderId.Text.ChangeType<int>(0);

                            db.Salons.Add(obj);
                            db.SaveChanges();
                            var tb = new Entities.Db.Seat();
                            for (int i = 1; i < Convert.ToUInt32(txtCapacity.Text);i++ )
                            {
                                tb.SalonId = obj.Id;
                                db.Seats.Add(tb);
                                db.SaveChanges();
                            }
                                DBUtils.AddOperationLog((CurrentUser)Session["currentUser"], "", "افزودن خدمت");
                            Message.Info("successful operaton ");
                            Response.Redirect("AbstractServices.aspx", false);
```

but i face with exception in FOR loop (line:db.SaveChanges();).
the exception is:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.

Comment: What is the inner exception?

Comment: in tb.SalonId, is SalonId a Primary Key ?

Comment: Could you add the information found from the inner exception link?

Comment: @Parnav Patel: no it's not

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to put `var tb = new Entities.Db.Seat();`
inside of the loop. Because currently you are trying to Add the same object to `db.Seats` but change its SalonId property each time. That's not good

Comment: i did but i get exception again:

An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.

Comment: It would be a great idea to post the most inner exception here to let us get a better idea

Comment: there is no link for inner exception. and now when i run i face with different exception but i didn,t change anything


An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.

Comment: To see ineer expection you should be debugging your application. Does that error happen if your `txtCapacity.Text` is equal to 2? Are you sure that you need to start the loop from 1 if you use '<' sign? Try to debug and check if the behaviour is the same for 1 loop iteration and for many